# How to get every character in a string in shell?

Tags: shell

eg.

I have a string:

st='abcd'

in C I can use st[0]、st[1]..to get the char at the index.
But I don't know how to do it in shell.

and I want to get every character in the string st, how can I get it in shell?

Comment: While I presume you're referring to one of the many *nix shells, I can't tell for sure. Please edit your question and be more specific. Also... what have you tried, what happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you're using bash, and that you want to iterate every char in the string to further manipulate it, you can do the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
str="abcd 01234"; 
for i in $(seq 0 $(( ${#str} - 1 )) ); do
    echo ${str:$i:1};
done
```

Or, if you want it in one line:

```
str="abcd 01234"; for i in $(seq 0 $(( ${#str} - 1 )) ); do echo ${str:$i:1};done
```

If you don't want to manipulate the chars, just print them separately, use the following instead:

```
echo "1234 5678" | fold -w1
```

Comment: Thank you, `${str,beg,len}`, a new knownledge to me